# WPF, silverlight video streaming, catch streamed video

Tags: wpf, silverlight, video, streaming

I would like to stream videos, and save it to the hard disc using WPF MediaElement. 
For example, I'm using this code to play a video from the net:

```
<MediaElement Source="http://some.url/video.wmv" />
```

I need to save somehow streamed media file to the hard disc.
Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Thanks!